# SoundJS Not Working After Upload

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm attempting to add sound to my HTML5 game using SoundJS, a free Javascript library (http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS).

I'm testing it out using the most basic sample program that's included in the zip.  It runs great when opening in a browser from my hard drive, but after uploading it, no sounds play when I load the page from the web.  The sound files are in the exact same place and folder as on my pc.

Has anyone successfully gotten this to work?

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
function init()
  {
  if (!createjs.Sound.initializeDefaultPlugins()) {return;}

  var audioPath = "sounds/";
  var manifest = [
    {id:"Music", src:"18-machinae_supremacy-lord_krutors_dominion.ogg"},
    {id:"Thunder", src:"Thunder1.ogg"}
    ];

  createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
  createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", handleLoad);
  createjs.Sound.registerManifest(manifest, audioPath);
  }

function handleLoad(event)
  {
  createjs.Sound.play(event.src);
  }
```

Comment: Can you check your console or network panel for errors? Bet you'll find some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on SoundJS and can confirm it works from servers, as you can see in the [examples](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/soundGrid).

As the above comment says, the best place to start is in developer console in your browser.

Potential sources of the issue are not including or having the wrong path for the js files that are loaded in the script tags, not including / wrong path for the sound files, and possibly but unlikely not setting the correct mime types on your server to properly return audio files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, OJay.  That definitely helps.  It's giving me a 404 (not found) error on both of the audio files, even though they're clearly there on the server.  I changed the sounds from ogg to different files in mp3 and it works fine.  It must be some sort of problem with my website not recognizing that file type, I assume.

Comment: I notice that it now works on the desktop browser, but not the phone, so that'll have to be my next thing to tackle.